# jQuery scroll to fadein and animate simultaneously on div

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-animate, fadein

I have been trying to get this jQuery correct, but I just can't seem to get it right. What I am trying to do is have a user scroll, and when they scroll to the corresponding pixel limit, jquery fadein and animate will occur, creating a cool little effect. I was trying to use fadeIn, but it didn't work simultaneously, so I am using `css`. The problem is that while I have it working, when I continue to scroll, the images continue to flicker off and on.

Here is the my code.

```
    $(window).bind("scroll", function() {
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > 560 ) {
        $('#subOverlay').css({'display':'block', 'opacity':'0'})
        .animate({'opacity':'1','left':'25%'}, 1500);
    } else {
        $("#subOverlay").stop().fadeOut();
    }
});
```

You will notice in my code above, I want the user to scroll to 560 pixels, and then have the effects work simultaneously. I have tried to correct this "flickering" but I just can't get it. I have tried using `.fadeIn(1000).animate({'opacity':'1','left':'25%'}, 1500);` but it doesn't create the effect I am trying to achieve simultaneously.

Please see the [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/dkonwdf6/1/) for an example of what I am talking about.  Can you help? Or point me in the right direction? Thank you.

Comment: What's wrong with the code above? (beside it's polluting the scroll event?)

Comment: Please post a fiddle so we can better understand your problem..

Comment: Ok, no problem, I will update that in 1 minute. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As much as possible, try to avoid using jQuery for CSS work. This includes `css`, `animate`, `fadeOut`, etc. Here's an example, where the JavaScript only toggles classes:

http://jsfiddle.net/05Leto4e/1/

Comment: thank you for your help. This will work. If you know how to create this without using CSS 'transition' that would be even better. A fadeIn and animate that works simultaneously? Otherwise I will have to account for that 'transition' with cross-browser support, right?

Comment: Yeah, the code I posted will help even if you want to use `animate` and `fadeIn`. The original problem is that the first part of the if statement is running hundreds of times a second once they've scrolled past 560. You need the `overlay_hidden` variable to ensure that you only run it once.